# JMeter Remote Server Freezes - Missing library and ConnectionTimeout exceptions

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter

I have setup an EC2 nano instance with OpenJDK11 and JMeter version 5.6.2. Managed to configure the server to accept proper commands from master Jmeter by setting the property *RMI_HOST_DEF* in jmeter-server file as follows:

```
RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-34-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Please note that using the IP Address failed to start the server. After ensuring both JMeters are running same version 5.6.2 and after sharing the *JKS* file between both applications, I attempted to Start the Remote Server with a basic plan.

After freezing for several minutes, the server ended up throwing a confusing error:

```
    2023-10-27 13:53:14,007 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
    2023-10-27 13:53:14,639 ERROR o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Exception registering implementation: [org.apache.jmeter.functions.TimeFunction] of interface: [interface org.apache.jmeter.functions.Function], a jar is probably missing
    java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.jmeter.functions.Function: Provider org.apache.jmeter.functions.TimeFunction could not be instantiated
```

The weird part is that it takes a long while to throw the error, after some Timeout event triggers. Which led me to review the second error:

```
    2023-10-27 13:57:35,694 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.29.128.1; nested exception is:
```

But I've configured the *rmi.server.hostname* (priori to this configuration the connection failed as the AWS NAT was returning the private IP address) to my local Jmeter. Did I configure this incorrectly? Do I need to configure again? I've noticed that the logs show the local IP address and warn of this error but it seems to conflict in some way with the hostname I defined.

Here's the full Log for the jmeter-server.log

```
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,473 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,529 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,530 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,531 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: java.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,531 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: server_port=1099
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,544 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2023 The Apache Software Foundation
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,544 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.6.2
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,549 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=11.0.20.1
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=6.2.0-1012-aws
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,550 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=true
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,551 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =536870912
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,551 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =1
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,569 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,570 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,570 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/home/ubuntu/jmeter
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,570 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/home/ubuntu/jmeter/bin
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,571 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/home/ubuntu/jmeter/bin
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,574 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 172.31.46.203 Name: ip-172-31-46-203 FullName: ip-172-31-46-203.ec2.internal
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,574 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: search_paths=/app1/lib;/app2/lib
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,575 WARN o.a.j.JMeter: Can't read /app1/lib
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,575 WARN o.a.j.JMeter: Can't read /app2/lib
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,656 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    2023-10-27 13:44:10,659 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=172.31.46.203
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,228 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.46.203,localport=50000]]
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,366 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Starting backing engine on 1099
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,369 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,370 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=172.31.46.203
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,370 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: IP address is a site-local address; this may cause problems with remote access.
        Can be overridden by defining the system property 'java.rmi.server.hostname' - see jmeter-server script file
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,370 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating RMI registry (server.rmi.create=true)
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,370 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,370 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=172.31.46.203
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,622 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.46.203,localport=1099]]
    2023-10-27 13:44:11,627 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Bound to RMI registry on port 1099
    2023-10-27 13:44:28,006 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2023-10-27 13:44:28,009 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2023-10-27 13:44:28,009 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2023-10-27 13:44:28,010 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
    2023-10-27 13:44:28,010 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
    2023-10-27 13:44:28,010 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
    2023-10-27 13:44:28,935 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
    2023-10-27 13:44:29,135 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
    2023-10-27 13:44:29,135 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run with stripAlsoOnError: true
    2023-10-27 13:44:29,315 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
    2023-10-27 13:44:29,316 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run with stripAlsoOnError: true
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,550 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating JMeter engine on host ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com base '.'
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,550 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Remote client host: 45.234.117.54
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,569 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/home/ubuntu/jmeter/bin'
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,582 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='.'
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,781 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Applying properties {}
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,965 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Running test
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,998 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
    2023-10-27 13:53:13,999 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
    2023-10-27 13:53:14,007 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
    2023-10-27 13:53:14,007 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
    2023-10-27 13:53:14,639 ERROR o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Exception registering implementation: [org.apache.jmeter.functions.TimeFunction] of interface: [interface org.apache.jmeter.functions.Function], a jar is probably missing
    java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.jmeter.functions.Function: Provider org.apache.jmeter.functions.TimeFunction could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:804) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:722) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.loadServices(ClassFinder.java:118) [jorphan.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.loadServicesAndScanJars(JMeterUtils.java:345) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.<clinit>(CompoundVariable.java:73) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.ValueReplacer.<init>(ValueReplacer.java:43) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.PreCompiler.<init>(PreCompiler.java:54) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:404) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780) ~[?:?]
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSMS
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCacheFactory.newBoundedLocalCache(LocalCacheFactory.java:95) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalManualCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:3423) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:3758) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.build(Caffeine.java:1104) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.functions.TimeFunction.<clinit>(TimeFunction.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.6.2]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780) ~[?:?]
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCacheFactory.newBoundedLocalCache(LocalCacheFactory.java:92) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalManualCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:3423) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:3758) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.build(Caffeine.java:1104) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.functions.TimeFunction.<clinit>(TimeFunction.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.6.2]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780) ~[?:?]
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527) ~[?:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:248) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SS.<init>(SS.java:31) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSMS.<init>(SSMS.java:62) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCacheFactory.newBoundedLocalCache(LocalCacheFactory.java:92) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalManualCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:3423) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:3758) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.build(Caffeine.java:1104) ~[caffeine-2.9.3.jar:?]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.testStarted(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:78) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:248) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:424) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:164) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.java:117) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617) ~[?:?]
        ... 14 more
    2023-10-27 13:57:35,694 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.29.128.1; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623) ~[?:?]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209) ~[?:?]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196) ~[?:?]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:132) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.testStarted(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:78) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:248) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:424) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:164) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.java:117) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617) ~[?:?]
        ... 14 more
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,766 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteTestListenerWrapper: Exception on testStarted on host ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.29.128.1; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623) ~[?:?]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209) ~[?:?]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196) ~[?:?]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:132) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217) ~[?:?]
        at   at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLRMIClientSocketFactory.java:117) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617) ~[?:?]
        ... 14 more
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,827 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Clínicos - Apertura de Ficha Paciente
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,833 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Clínicos - Apertura de Ficha Paciente.
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,833 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Test will stop on error
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,834 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=0 delayedStart=false
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,865 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,866 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
    2023-10-27 13:59:46,883 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: ec2-34-201-171-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com-Clínicos - Apertura de Ficha Paciente 1-1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) user manual entry:

> If you don't want to put JMeter plugin jars in the lib/ext directory, then define the property search_paths in jmeter.properties.

You've set the `search_paths` property to `/app1/lib;/app2/lib` and these folders don't seem to contain [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions/5.6.2) file

So it's an issue with your JMeter installation. Either unset the property of perform full [clean install of the latest stable JMeter version](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) because who knows what else is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked around and see no ApacheJmeter_functions.jar JAR file, only ApacheJmeter.jar. Am I supposed to download it separately? Running latest version 5.6.2 already